# Signing a contract in a foreign language

Tags: job-offer, contracts, relocation

I have this offer from a Bulgarian company which they send me the contract in both English and Bulgarian, but they have this statement at the end of the contract?

[image]

It says the Bulgarian version will prevail in case of discrepancy, should I sign it like this? What should I do if they won't be able to change this, so the English version prevails?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you expect them to state a prefered language?

Comment: The "should I sign this" is unanswerable; it's up to you. So, you have already asked them to change that so the English version prevails? Or you have not yet done that?

Comment: Why don't you translate the Bulgarian version and have an attorney review it?

Comment: @SolarMike my concern is the preferred language is the one I don't understand.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I asked them to use English, but their answer was "This is a standard clause for contracts in Bulgaria"

Comment: @aldokkani yup, it's standard as I said in my answer. It's pretty standard in many countries it seems... I'd say that your best options are to get someone you trust (and that knows) translate it so you are sure it matches your English copy...

Comment: So sign a contract in a country that speaks a  language you do understand.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the advice, even though it doesn't answer any question I asked.

Comment: As you stated "my concern is the preferred language is the one I don’t understand" leads to the logical conclusion of signing a contract with a country speaking your preferred language…

Comment: @joeqwerty "*Why don't you translate the Bulgarian version and have an attorney review it?*" Not saying that your suggestion is wrong. It is just noteworthy that in case of translation discrepancies the OP would have a claim against the translator (unless the OP's contract with the translator includes some sort of waiver) and not against the company.

Comment: @aldokkani "*their answer was "This is a standard clause for contracts in Bulgaria"*". The fact or pretext that something is just "*standard for contracts*" is never a good reason for doing so. One main purpose of written --or otherwise provable-- contracts is to indicate what conditions between the parties will depart from common practice. If a dispute is intended to be litigated in a Bulgarian tribunal, it is understandable why at least one party wants the contract in Bulgarian language to be the official one. But ultimately what matters is what the parties *agree*, not what is standard.

Comment: Very common. For example in Mexico, any contract not in Spanish is unenforceable, and if you're provided an English copy with any discrepancy, it doesn't matter, Spanish one is the only one considered. It's likely they're just putting that on there so that you *understand* that is the situation, to prevent questions in the future. Well written I would say

Comment: What I do, living abroad and not being fluent, is I use the Google Lens app to take a photo of contract pages, and it translates the entire photo / page in real time

Answer (score 16):

I am not a lawyer, but I think this is pretty standard when dealing with two languages (I've seen these translated copies before).

The thing is that, according to your post, this company is Bulgarian and their official language is such. Therefore, legal documents in that country have to be in the official language (again, IANAL, but this is pretty standard).

They are taking the time to translate it to English so you can understand and read it, but the legally binding document seems to be the Bulgarian copy.

If you fear that they might be omitting certain things in the English version that are in the Bulgarian version, then consider getting an official, legal translator (notice the "legal" word; translating regular documents is quite different from translating legal documents).

Comment: +1. IANAL, but common sense suggests that any contract should be enforceable in court, so if the contract is signed under Bulgarian laws and, if disputed, will be tried in Bulgarian court, it's only expected that it should be written in Bulgaria official language.

Comment: @IgorG "*if the contract is signed under Bulgarian laws and, if disputed, will be tried in Bulgarian court*". Not necessarily. Contracts can specify that any dispute will be litigated elsewhere. Also the facts of the case (example: he performs the contract elsewhere or the contract was signed outside Bulgaria) *might* entitle the OP to litigate it in a non-Bulgarian court if the matter is left unspecified. The fact that the contract is in Bulgarian language and with a Bulgarian company does not imply that it is performed (or even signed) in Bulgaria.

Answer (score 12):

They should not be expected to change it so that English prevails. That requires time, money and bureaucracy on their part, creates potential ongoing uncertainty for them, and delays both parties. It's on you to hire an English speaking Bulgarian lawyer if you are concerned.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is the document was theoretically written in Bulgarian, it's to safeguard them if their translation is not perfect.

I'm not sure if Bulgarian is a precise language, if you feel that anything needs clarification then get that done before signing. In my own country it is standard for an English copy to be made but the local copy to take precedence. However the local language is very open to interpretation which often gets foreigners into trouble in disputes.

Answer (score 1):

You are considering signing a legal document. Just consult a lawyer (preferably a Bulgarian one or someone who understands both languages fluently and is well-versed with Bulgarian law). It won't cost you much at all to ask a lawyer if the two documents say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

if you fear they're trying to pull one on you and give you a different English text as compared to the Bulgarian text, that's a major signal that you shouldn't want to work for them in the first place.

When in doubt, get a translator of your own and get the Bulgarian copy translated, then compare that with the version supplied to you. If there are differences that are more than cosmetic, discuss them with your contacts within the company and ask.

In the end, if the contract is enforced under Bulgarian law and the Bulgarian language version is legally binding, that will be the one enforced and you'll have to sign it to start working there. That's just the way it is in many countries.

Comment: You're far better consulting a lawyer (with appropriate skills) than a translator. A lawyer will be able to tell you if the contract terms are legally identical (and will have liability insurance if they get it wrong).

Comment: @StuartF the lawyer would need a translator for that of course :)